# North orientations in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm wondering if anyone can explain what the different north orientations are in QGIS map composer.

What is the default map edge aligned with?

When I place a north arrow up against it, neither the grid north or true north orientation option align with the map edge.

Comment: Please provide images showing what you're talking about, as well as your CRS settings, and your map item settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think i figured it out. I was using a north arrow and placing it right up beside my grid border. with the north arrow setting on "grid north" the north arrow should run parallel with the map edge but it wasn't.

Turns out the north arrow SVG I was using had a tiny taper in the image which made it look like the arrow was on a different angle. But upon trying another arrow it was parallel.